# Outbound connection intermittent failed to response

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes, kube-dns, kube-proxy, calico

I'm experiencing intermittent failed to response when make an outbound connection such as RPC call, it is logged by my application (Java) like this :

`org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: RPC_SERVER.com:443 failed to respond !`

**Outbound connection flow**

Kubernetes Node -> ELB for internal NGINX -> internal NGINX ->[Upstream To]-> ELB RPC server -> RPC server instance

This problem is not occurred on usual EC2 (AWS).

I'm able to reproduce on my localhost by doing this

1. Run main application which act as client in port 9200
2. Run RPC server in port 9205
3. Client will make a connection to server using port 9202
4. Run `$ socat TCP4-LISTEN:9202,reuseaddr TCP4:localhost:9205` that will listen on port 9202 and then forward it to 9205 (RPC Server)
5. Add rules on iptables using `$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9202 -j DROP`
6. Trigger a RPC calling, and it will return the same error message as I desrcibe before

**Hypothesis**

Caused by NAT on kubernetes, as far as I know, NAT is using `conntrack`, `conntrack` and break the TCP connection if it was idle for some period of time, client will assume the connection is still established although it isn't. (CMIIW)

I also have tried scaling `kube-dns` into 10 replica, and the problem still occurred.

**Node Specification**

Use calico as network plugin

`$ sysctl -a | grep conntrack`

```
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_acct = 0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_buckets = 65536
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_checksum = 1
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_count = 1585
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_events = 1
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_expect_max = 1024
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_generic_timeout = 600
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_helper = 1
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_icmp_timeout = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_log_invalid = 0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 262144
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_be_liberal = 0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_loose = 1
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_max_retrans = 3
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close = 10
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait = 3600
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 86400
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_fin_wait = 120
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_last_ack = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_max_retrans = 300
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_recv = 60
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_sent = 120
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait = 120
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_unacknowledged = 300
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_timestamp = 0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_udp_timeout = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_udp_timeout_stream = 180
net.nf_conntrack_max = 262144
```

**Kubelet config**

```
[Service]
Restart=always
Environment="KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS=--kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --require-kubeconfig=true"
Environment="KUBELET_SYSTEM_PODS_ARGS=--pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests --allow-privileged=true"
Environment="KUBELET_NETWORK_ARGS=--network-plugin=cni --cni-conf-dir=/etc/cni/net.d --cni-bin-dir=/opt/cni/bin"
Environment="KUBELET_DNS_ARGS=--cluster-dns=10.96.0.10 --cluster-domain=cluster.local"
Environment="KUBELET_AUTHZ_ARGS=--authorization-mode=Webhook --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt"
Environment="KUBELET_CADVISOR_ARGS=--cadvisor-port=0"
Environment="KUBELET_CLOUD_ARGS=--cloud-provider=aws"
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_SYSTEM_PODS_ARGS $KUBELET_NETWORK_ARGS $KUBELET_DNS_ARGS $KUBELET_AUTHZ_ARGS $KUBELET_CADVISOR_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS $KUBELET_CLOUD_ARGS
```

**Kubectl version**

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.5", GitCommit:"17d7182a7ccbb167074be7a87f0a68bd00d58d97", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-08-31T09:14:02Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.7", GitCommit:"8e1552342355496b62754e61ad5f802a0f3f1fa7", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-09-28T23:56:03Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

**Kube-proxy Log**

```
W1004 05:34:17.400700       8 server.go:190] WARNING: all flags other than --config, --write-config-to, and --cleanup-iptables are deprecated. Please begin using a config file ASAP.
I1004 05:34:17.405871       8 server.go:478] Using iptables Proxier.
W1004 05:34:17.414111       8 server.go:787] Failed to retrieve node info: nodes "ip-172-30-1-20" not found
W1004 05:34:17.414174       8 proxier.go:483] invalid nodeIP, initializing kube-proxy with 127.0.0.1 as nodeIP
I1004 05:34:17.414288       8 server.go:513] Tearing down userspace rules.
I1004 05:34:17.443472       8 conntrack.go:98] Set sysctl 'net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max' to 262144
I1004 05:34:17.443518       8 conntrack.go:52] Setting nf_conntrack_max to 262144
I1004 05:34:17.443555       8 conntrack.go:98] Set sysctl 'net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established' to 86400
I1004 05:34:17.443584       8 conntrack.go:98] Set sysctl 'net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait' to 3600
I1004 05:34:17.443851       8 config.go:102] Starting endpoints config controller
I1004 05:34:17.443888       8 config.go:202] Starting service config controller
I1004 05:34:17.443890       8 controller_utils.go:994] Waiting for caches to sync for endpoints config controller
I1004 05:34:17.443916       8 controller_utils.go:994] Waiting for caches to sync for service config controller
I1004 05:34:17.544155       8 controller_utils.go:1001] Caches are synced for service config controller
I1004 05:34:17.544155       8 controller_utils.go:1001] Caches are synced for endpoints config controller
```

`$ lsb_release -s -d`
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 2):

Check the value of `sysctl net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait` inside the pod that contains your program. It is possible that the value on the node that you listed (3600) isn't the same as the value inside the pod.

If the value in the pod is too small (e.g. 60), and your Java client half-closes the TCP connection with a FIN when it finishes transmitting, but the response takes longer than the close_wait timeout to arrive, nf_conntrack will lose the connection state and your client program will not receive the response.

You may need to change the behavior of the client program to not use a TCP half-close, OR modify the value of `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait` to be larger. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/sysctl-cluster/.